# Compare integral parts of 2 floats or doubles; most efficient way

Tags: c++, int, double, integral

I want to check if the integral parts of 2 floats or doubles are equal.

Different solutions come to mind, but I don't know what's the fastest one, cross-CPU-wise.

- Convert the floats to ints?
- Use `modf` to get the integral parts?
- Use `floor`?

For the edge-case of comparing around zero, like `areIntegralsEqual(0.5, -0.5)`, I should get a ***false*** in this case. I suspect that the 1st solution wouldn't work correctly here, but if it's an order of magnitude faster than the other two solutions, I would consider hacking it around.

Comment: You don't agree that integer parts of `-0.5` and `0.5` are equal? What about `-1.5` and `1.5`?

Comment: Did you experiment yourself? What if you get answers, naming one of the methods to be the fastest cross-CPU-wise and then you measure yourself and discover that it is actually the slowest? What kind of answers do you expect?

Comment: @Yola No, I would want `-0.0` and `0.0` to be different, in my case

Comment: @Yunnosch I have access to just x86. I am looking for a solution that is "balanced", so it's not super-slow on, say, ARM.

Comment: What rounding rule do you want to use to get the integral parts? Both round-towards-zero and round-to-nearest with ties rounding to even map both 0.5 and -0.5 to zero.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan `floor` and `modf` do the work in my case. The `modf` returns `0.0` and `-0.0` (but I don't know yet how to find that they are not identical)

Comment: @BillKotsias I only meant the 0.5 and -0.5 case as an example, The first step to even identifying a functionally correct solution is a precise and complete definition of what you mean by "the integral part" of a float.